# Getting a flowdocument from a xaml template file

Tags: wpf, xaml, flowdocument

I got a Xaml file that starts like this:

```
  <FlowDocument
       x:Name="flowDocument"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       xmlns:Drawing="clr-namespace:System.Drawing;assembly=System.Drawing"
```

Current solution uses a StremReader by referring to the physical path of the xaml file with the flowdocument and then parses data into the template.

This is not a valid solution, so I need to get the flowdocument withouth referring to the physical path.

I would like to use the xmlns namespace or similar in my C# code and do like

```
string result = XamlWriter.Save(flowDocument)
```

And use the result for parsing.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly, you want to get the FlowDocument from a string? You can do this with `XamlReader.Parse`:

```
string result = XamlWriter.Save(flowDocument);
FlowDocument new_doc = (FlowDocument)XamlReader.Parse(result);
```

**EDIT:** If the XAML file is a part of your project, you can mark it as EmbeddedResource and use the following to load it:

```
Stream doc_stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                            .GetManifestResourceStream("YourNamespace.YourFile.xaml");
FlowDocument doc = (FlowDocument)XamlReader.Load(doc_stream);
```

Comment: Sorry for my clumsy presentation of my problem.
I do have a xaml file with the flowdocument xaml. 
I want to get my hands on the content of the xaml file, a string would be uber-nice.

Comment: If your XAML is a part of your project, you can use the resource method. Otherwise, you have to locate it on disk somehow.