# How do I reference my FlowDocument

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

I've defined a FlowDocument in a WPF control library (Add New Item..., FlowDocument --  is the root element of the file).  I intend this to be used in several contexts such as in a user control or on a window, referenced in code for data-binding and export to xps, etc.  But I can't figure out how to get a reference to an instance of this document.  It doesn't seem to create an object in the compiled assembly.

More specifically, this is my problem

```
<MyUserControl ........ >
  <FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
    <!-- doesn't work --><namespaceRef:MyFlowDocument /> 
  <FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
</MyUserControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably to put your FlowDocument inside a Resource Dictionary and then use the x:Key like this

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <FlowDocument x:Key="myFlowDocument" ..>
    </FlowDocument>
</ResourceDictionary>

<FlowDocumentScrollViewer Name="flowDocumentScrollViewer">
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="myFlowDocument"/>
</FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

Otherwise you'll have to set the FlowDocument to build action Embedded Resource and lode it in code behind with something like this

```
Stream flowDocumentStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("DocumentNameSpace.FlowDocumentName.xaml");
FlowDocument flowDocument = (FlowDocument)XamlReader.Load(flowDocumentStream);
flowDocumentScrollViewer.Document = flowDocument;
```

**Update**
I think it might be possible to use an ObjectDataProvider to load the FlowDocument if you want to look into it. Anyway, a ResourceDictionary seems like the easy way out.

Comment: I guess that's reasonable...but in this case, what is the purpose of the "FlowDocument" template option in the Add New Item dialog?  Is that solely for embedded resources?

Comment: Yes, I'm wondering the same thing. Maybe there is a way to accomplish this, but I've never seen it. Maybe someone will give you a better answer shortly :)

Comment: Here's some links to similar issues. http://www.netframeworkdev.com/windows-presentation-foundation-wpf/loading-a-flowdocument-into-a-richtextbox-in-xaml-87774.shtml

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897505/getting-a-flowdocument-from-a-xaml-template-file